# What is the mistake in this URL loop?

Tags: r, url, href, rvest

For one url the code works, but for multiple urls in a list this does not work, gives an error. I'm new to r, please help.

```
library(rvest)


for (url in data_list){

webpage = read_html(url)


extracted_urls = webpage %>%
rvest::html_nodes("a") %>%
rvest::html_attr("href")
extracted_urls = extracted_urls[grep("roster", extracted_urls)]
extracted_urls}
```

Error:

`x` must be a string of length 1

---

### Edit

Links in OP's comment.

```
data_list <- c(
  "ephsports.williams.edu", 
  "wilsonphoenix.com", 
  "wingatebulldogs.com", 
  "ycpspartans.com"
)
```

Comment: At some point your code created a length-0 result. Where? Hard to say. Do a traceback() or whatever the rlang equivalent might be.

Comment: If its possible provide the urls.

Comment: ["https://ephsports.williams.edu/" ,"https://wilsonphoenix.com/",    "https://wingatebulldogs.com/" ,"https://ycpspartans.com/"]

Comment: All urls are timing out. Are you sure they are correct?

Comment: Only links https://wingatebulldogs.com/ and https://wilsonphoenix.com/ are working

Comment: Can you correct the code with some random url. @NadPat

Answer (score 0):

Variables created in a for loop get overwritten each iteration. Here, extracted_urls gets repeatedly clobbered. Creating a receiver object outside the loop (try r <- list()) permits adding results stepwise to an object in the global environment, which will remain accessible outside the local environment within the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the urls are not working, we can skip them using `possibly` function.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

data_list <- c(
  'https://wilsonphoenix.com', 
 'https://wingatebulldogs.com',
'https://ycpspartans.com/sorry.ashx'
)
#the third link is broken 

# we create a function to get required info. 
roster = function(x){ 
webpage = read_html(x)
extracted_urls = webpage %>%
  rvest::html_nodes("a") %>%
  rvest::html_attr("href")
extracted_urls = extracted_urls[grep("roster", extracted_urls)]
extracted_urls}
}
```

Now we loop over vector containing urls `data_list` and skipping the one with errors.

```
df <- map(data_list, 
                  possibly(roster, otherwise = NA_character_))
```